# Unit conversion kilometers to miles doesn't return the expected result

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to convert my result from kilometers to miles but the result I get isn't correct.

What seems to be the problem here?

```
when {
    // TIME: To calculate your time, fill in your distance and pace
    time == null -> {
        val calculatedTime = distance!!.toLong() * timeToSeconds(pace.toString())
        result.text = "The runner's time is ${secondsToTime(calculatedTime)}"
    }
    // DISTANCE: To calculate your distance, fill in your time and pace
    distance == null -> {
        val calculatedDistance = ((timeToSeconds(time).div(timeToSeconds
        (pace.toString()))) * 0.621371).format(2)
        result.text = "Distance is $calculatedDistance Miles"
    }
    // PACE: To calculate your pace, fill in your time and distance
    pace == null -> {
        // Calculate Pace
        val calculatedPace: Long = timeToSeconds(time).toLong() / distance.toLong()

        Log.i("PaceSeconds", calculatedPace.toString() +
                secondsToTime(calculatedPace))

        result.text = "The runner's pace in miles is ${secondsToTime(calculatedPace)}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post just one part of the code with its inputs and expected outputs. Also, if you don't know what's happening when your code is executed, use the debugger to follow the values in it.

Comment: Please provide more details about what is not correct, what you expect from this code and what research you have already done. Questions asking for debugging help and only providing the sources without an explanation are considered off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: "Android not applying math correclty" that's quite a statement :D I suggest you to write a small test case, to verify your calculations are correct

Comment: A simple calculation: for 10:12 (minutes and seconds) at a pace of 1:23 (mm:ss again) the distance in KM is 7.37 (and I get that value correctly). Although, when I convert it to Miles, it gives me 4.35 when it should give me 4.58 Miles

Comment: I did verify the calculations on a paper before writing them :)

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the val I calculate it and I see the value being passed as 4.35 instead of 4.58. So weird. I even tried using toDouble

Answer (score 0):

This is a rounding issue. Lets break it down:

```
val timeInSeconds = timeToSeconds(time)
val paceInSeconds = timeToSeconds(pace)
val timeDivPace = timeInSeconds.div(paceInSeconds)
val calculatedDistance = timeDivPace * 0.621371
```

Using the sample data from your comment, `timeInSeconds` is 612 and `paceInSeconds` is 83. You expect `timeDivPace` to be 7.373494 but it actually is 7 because a division of two integers returns an integer as result.

The fix is simple: convert either the dividend or the divisor to float, e.g.:

```
val timeDivPace = timeInSeconds.div(paceInSeconds.toFloat())
```